# sectioning content within a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

Building a wordpress site that needs to organize content by stream - e.g Mechanical, Electrical etc. Also, each page needs sections like News, Articles events etc. If you pick one page (say Mechanical) it has to have the following sections

- News
- Articles (category:articles)
- Events (category:events)

The other streams will have the same sections as well

Is there a plugin for achieving or would I be better off building a template page for each vertical and writing php code? Shown code for a page with a single section.

```
  <?php           
  $args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 1,
'category_name'    => 'news',
'orderby'          => 'date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 


    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
  //EXAMPLE NEWS SECTION 
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
      the_content();          
      echo $content;
      }

  } else {
      // no posts found

  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you could just write a plugin which does that filtering.
Said plugin would have some kind on [shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/) that would take a parameter (category for instance) and would return or echo all the posts associated with that category.

Shortcode registration :

```
add_action('init','register_shortcode');
function register_shortcode(){
  add_shortcode('shortcode_name', 'shortcode_function');
}
```

Shortcode function:

```
function shortcode_function($attr){
  $attr = shortcode_atts(array('category' => 'default'),$attr); //Setting defaults parameters
  $args = array(
    'category_name'    => $attr['category'],
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
    );

  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
      //echo other html related stuff
      the_title();
      the_content();          
    }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
[shortcode_name category='news']
[shortcode_name] //category defaults at 'default'
```

In your case a page could be something like that

```
<div>
  News : <br/>
  [shortcode_name category='news']
</div>
<div>
  Articles : <br/>
  [shortcode_name category='articles']
</div>
<div>
  Events : <br/>
  [shortcode_name category='events']
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is *one* right way to do this... it depends on the scenario... How many posts, how often do sections or "main streams" get added / change, do you need other stuff on the pages etc.

One pretty simple and easily maintained solution would be to:

`1.` Add `mechanical`, `electrical`, etc. as categories alongside `news`, `articles` and `events`

`2.` Modify (or add) `category.php` to repeat the loop three times, and only display the posts that belong to each section (other category):

```
//Loop your sections
foreach(array('news', 'articles', 'events') as $category) {
    echo '<h2>' . $category . '</h2>';
    //Loop posts
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        //Check if post is in section (by slug!)
        if ( in_category($category) ) {
            the_title();
            the_content();
        }
    }
    //Start the loop over
    rewind_posts();
}
```

Now just assign each post to one (or more) "parents", fx `mechanical`, and also to one (and only one) of `news`, `articles` or `events`...

- If you go to the archive page of `mechanical` you get three sections
- if you go to `news` you get all news (but also two empty sections, so you should of course check for that).

Note that this could be done using tags or even a custom taxonomy if you wanted, you'd just need to edit a different theme file - see the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

**Beware though** that this will not work very nicely with pagination, so if that is a concern you *will* need to deal with that.